# Redirect All the crawlers to A specific action through routes.rb Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I need to redirect all the `web crawlers` e.g `facebook` / `google` /`twitter` to a specific action in my `routes.rb` of Rails API . I came to know that it can be done by `constraints` in `Ruby On Rails` . But i don't know how to do that . Any help will be appreciating !

Comment: what is your goal with the crawlers? Do you really have to verify a request was made by a crawler?

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn yes dear

Answer (score 0):

What's about using ApplicationController + the browser gem? https://github.com/fnando/browser:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    #...
    before_action :check_if_is_crawler

    def check_if_is_crawler
       browser = Browser.new(request.headers['User-Agent'])
       if browser.bot?
         #Do whatever you want here.
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: dear ,is there any way we can check it in routes.rb

Comment: But why? Routes are not here for routing by user agent. 
If you really want to handle it at low level, check how to setup a middleware. Not so hard to do. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html